# Binding to a property not declared in the current project

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I have the following sample code:

```
static class Test
{
    public WordBase FindWord( String word )
    {
        return (WordBase)Data.Vocabulary.Where( a => a.Name == word ).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

static class Data
{
    public List<WordBase> Vocabulary = new List<WordBase>();
}

class WordBase
{
    public UInt32 Id { get; protected set; }
    public String Name { get; protected set; }

    public WordBase( UInt32 id, String name )
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is to move the `Data` class into an external assembly that will be loaded via reflection.  The reason for this is that I am writing a text based adventure game creator that allows multiple episode to be chained together, where each assembly will contain the game data and logic for each episode.

The problem I am having is that the `FindWord` method is going to fail because `Data.Vocabulary` won't exist in the current project; remember it's been moved out  to an externally loaded assembly so there won't be any strongly typed reference to it.

I think that I need to create some sort of contract, either by an interface or an abstract class, so that the `FindWord` method can bind to the `Data.Vocabulary` property.

What's the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a satelite assembly containing a Interface.

For example:

PluginBase containing a interface that is referenced in both assemblies (gameplugin/main game)

```
public Interface Test
{
    WordBase FindWord( String word );
}
```

Notice the WordBase class must be in the PluginBase.dll also.

This is just an example, there are tons of plugin architectures already thought by others. You could look at those.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use static classes.

```
public interface IData
{
    IEnumerable<IWord> Vocabulary { get; }
}

public interface ITest
{
    IWord FindWord(string word);
}
```

Using interfaces allows a separation from implementation, so the caller doesn't need to know about the implementation details.

This way you can load the assembly that contains the definition at runtime and the code that depends on the interface won't care.